# Azure DevOps - Automated Pipeline Creation

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I'm new to Azure DevOps, and I was wondering if there was a way to automatically detected a .yml build file and create a pipeline without having to interact with the site.

I have tried creating a file called azure-pipelines.yml in the root of the repo, with no luck.

Is there anyway to automatically create pipelines? Like how Jenkins detects a Jenkinsfile?

Comment: Agree with Krzysztof Madej, there is no such way to achieve this. If you want to do that, you have to create your scripts to monitor your repo. To invoke the REST API to create the pipeline when it is detected that there is a new YAML creation in the repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this is nott possible out of the box, because YAML file is not always pipeline definition. You my try to figure out if it is trully is, however you need to listen for repo changes and in fact you can do this via another pipeline ;) for instance as this:

- check if commit has a new yaml file added
- verify if the file is pipeline
- create a pipeline using azure cli (for instance)

However, this would be quite a lot of work and then you need to create such pipeline in every repo you want to have this detection enabled.